# Call a function only once in if statement (the pythonic way)

Tags: python-3.x

While coding, I often have this structure of code.

Some function returns and objet and if this object is not `None`, then I use it

If I don't want to call the function twice (it is costly and may have side effect), I have to use a temporary variable to keep the result:

```py
temp = get_object()
if temp:
    do_something_with_object(temp)
```

Is there a more pythonic way to write this?

Comment: In Python 3.8 you will have `:=` assignment.

Comment: Do you want to do nothing in the case of `None`? `or` could be used here if you want to use alternate data. `get_object() or default_data`.

Comment: @AndrejKesely Exactly what I have in mind! Feel free to make an elaborate answer (ref: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prior to Python 3.8 there isn't clear solution to this problem. With Python 3.8, there will be new feature called `Assignment expressions` a.k.a `:=` assignment ([what's new in python 3.8](https://docs.python.org/3.8/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions)).

It basically means you'll be able do this in your code:

```
if (n := get_object()):
    do_something(n)
```

Link to [PEP-572](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0572/).